# ls to list files sorted by filename without the extension

Tags: ls

I want to list a bunch of files that are sorted by their names excluding the file extension. I have these files in a directory

```
$ls 
mobility_arXiv.tex
mobility_SR.bbl
paper-hj-mm.tex
paper-hj-mm-vp-rkp.tex
paper-hj.tex
```

I want the output to be

```
mobility_arXiv.tex
mobility_SR.bbl
paper-hj.tex
paper-hj-mm.tex
paper-hj-mm-vp-rkp.tex
```

Is there a way to achieve this.

Comment: In Linux it doesn't care if it's an extension or not - it's part of a filename. It just happens to be that Dash(-) has a 0x2D hex code and Dot has a 0x2E hex code, so the dash precedes in alphabetic order

Comment: I assume you meant your second snippet to exclude the '.EXT' parts..??

Comment: @Ashtray, Thanks for the explanation. But why is then `paper-hj-mm.tex` listed before `paper-hj-mm-vp-rkp.tex`

Comment: @imsc can't really say, but I think they have some sorting rule for each character encoding. Still, `sort` or `ls` utility doesn't give a damn about file extension

Comment: @Ashtray indeed `LANG=C ls` will sort irrespective of extension, and will thus be an easy solution for this question. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18451819

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pipe the output of `ls` into `cut`, which cuts fields, specifying "." as the delimiter. The result can then be sorted by piping into `sort`.

```
ls | cut -f 1 -d '.' | sort
```

If you need to handle dots "." in the filename you can use

```
ls | rev | cut -d . -f 2- | rev | sort
```

This works by first reversing each listing returned by ls, then cutting away the first (originally last) field, then reversing again.

NOTE: Cannot be used with colour output

If you wanted to keep the extension anyway, and just sort by the first part of the filename you can use

```
ls | sort -k 1,1 -t .
```

Here you're telling sort to use "." as the delimiter and sort according to key(field) 1.

Comment: What if I have more than a single dot in a filename? It might work in this specific case, but it's no universal at all

Comment: Sorry, my question was bit confusing. I want the sort order to be different.

Comment: @Ashtray: Updated with dot handling.

Comment: @imsc: I updated to include sorting, as well as dot in filename handling.

Comment: @imsc: I also added the solution if you wanted to keep the extension but sort just from the first part of the filename

Answer (score 2):

The **ls** command sorts files by **filename** alphabetically ascending by default. The extension is part of the filename so the best you can do, if you don't need the extension in the output is:

```
ls | cut -f 1 -d '.' | sort
```

UPDATE

A better solution:

```
ls | sort -k 1,1 -t .
```

Here sort is told to use just field number 1 and the dot as field separator. So it's ignoring the extension but not cutting it out.

Comment: Is there a way to get the extension back after sorting?

Comment: Yes. Just found a better way. Check my update.